# AngularJS Declaring Multiple Controllers in 1 app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble declaring 2 controllers in 1 app.  My guess is it's a syntax error, but not totally sure.

The error message I receive is that "people is not defined".

//this is my app file

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


 myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
 $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
 $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
 });



   myApp.controller('controller1', function($scope) {

   var pets = [
   {animal: "dog", years: "3 Years"},
   {animal: "dog", years: "1 Years"},
   ];});


   myApp.controller('controller2', function($scope) {


   var people = [
   {name: "john", bday: "september"},
   {name: "nancy",bday: "december"},
   ];
   });
```

On my html page, I am simply writing some javascript that attempts to get the length of the people array.

```
  var totalpeople = people.length;
```

Note:  Not sure if this is important information, but I declare my app in the html tag.

update:
here some some basic pseudo code on my html page.

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <script>
    var totalpeople = people.length;
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-controler="controller1">
    <table><tr ng-repeat="rows in pets">
    <td>{[{pets.animal}]}</td><td>{[{pets.year}]}</td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    <div ng-controler="controller2">
    <table><tr ng-repeat="rows in people">
    <td>{[{pets.name}]}</td><td>{[{pets.bday}]}</td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    <div>
    <table><tr>
    <td><script>//not actually doing this, but totalpeople goes here </script></td>
    </tr>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: show where you are calling `people`.

Comment: can you share you html as well, if you have plunker it will be easier

Comment: Your snippet isn't clear at all, provide a well-intentation.

By the way, you can't put a comma on a last element in array.

Comment: You have not exposed `people` or `pets` in your controllers. You would want to declare them as `this.people` and `this.pets` respectively.

Comment: @Alex Rumba just updated some HTML

Comment: updated the plunker.see my answer. Updated it just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a lots of errors in the html as well as in the script section. Like you have mispelled the `ng-controller` to **ng-controler**. And, ng-repeat logic is all wrong.You have missing table tags and more. I don't know why you would want to interpolate **{{}}** to use **{[{}]}**.

Here is the working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qs7mCrmElXGqGHdKAmNH?p=preview

```
    <html>
        <head>
          <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="controller1">
            <table><tr ng-repeat="rows in pets">
            <td>{[{rows.animal}]}</td><td>{[{rows.years}]}</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
              Total pets:{[{count}]}
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="controller2">
        <table><tr ng-repeat="rows in people">
        <td>{[{rows.name}]}</td><td>{[{rows.bday}]}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
         <br>
                  Total Pets:
                 <span id="show"></span>
    <script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


     myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
     $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
     $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
     });



       myApp.controller('controller1', function($scope) {

       $scope.pets = [
       {animal: "dog", years: "3 Years"},
       {animal: "dog", years: "1 Years"}
       ];
       $scope.count = $scope.pets.length;
       document.getElementById('show').innerText=$scope.count;//use directive to achieve this,using jquery inside controller is bad practise. Used just for the purpose of demo.
});


       myApp.controller('controller2', function($scope) {
       $scope.people = [
       {name: "john", bday: "september"},
       {name: "nancy",bday: "december"},
       ];
       });
    </script>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: @ Alex Rumba this makes sense.  Sorry for the sloppy pseudo code, was trying to get something up quickly. Thank you.  But how about my pets.length?  I still want to reference that elsewhere in my HTML further down on my page.

Comment: okay updated the plunker for count as well. Does that satisfy your need?

Comment: ok - So I need to make sure I reference it within my controller area.  Is there anyway I can reference it outside that area?

Comment: well you can either using jquery inside the controller which is not recommended, but will work. You should use directive for that purpose. I will simply give you an example using javascript inside controller

Comment: Sharing datas in between controllers has been discussed a lot in other threads. So, i suppose you won't be asking that. :)

Answer (score 0):

> On my html page, I am simply writing some javascript that attempts to
>   get the length of the people array.

Are you sure you expect `people` to be available in the global scope (i.e. a property of `window` object)?

Now let's simplify the code as follows:

```
function doStuff() {
   var people = "whatever";
}

doStuff();

// Is "people" variable available?
```

The answer is **no**, it's not available because it's a `doStuff` function local variable.

This isn't an Angular-specific issue, but it's how variable scoping works in JavaScript (and practically in any language).

Actually, Angular tries to avoid adding *garbage* to the global scope and you need to use built-in data-binding to show values in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to write javascript in your view to get the length?

```
   $scope.people = [
      {name: "john", bday: "september"},
      {name: "nancy",bday: "december"},
   ];
```

Can then just do people.length in your view.

Seeing the context that you are trying to call it would help though.